# How can I find a static wordpress page in the dashboard?

Tags: wordpress

I have a static Wordpress page that has no direct link to edit the page in the dashboard and I cannot find it by site title or tag.  I can customize it through the front end, but I cannot edit contents.  It does have the links and notes to blog posts.  Any ideas????

Answer (score 0):

if its homepage than may be frontpage.php template is used so you are not able to edit and content might be pulled from other post or page.or can be blog posts page home.php check theme file and you should know. ALso use (what the file) plugin to detct which template file a page is using

Comment: Thanks Sandeep!  That's the issue, I'm working through the dashboard with no access to the file system.  The page doesn't come up in the dashboard. I have no authority to add a plugin so my hands are tied.   Thanks again as this is what I thought.